# Postgres Deadlock in Trigger after Select ... For Update

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

I'm having trouble with what I think is a deadlock when a trigger is fired after a lock. Can you see any reason why there would be a deadlock in the situation described by this pseudo code:

- in a single transaction, started in the Java by `Jdbi.inTransaction()`

  - select for update on a row by unique ID in table 1
  - insert new record into table 2

    - fires a trigger that attempts to update the row in table 1

It appears that the last query that is fired by the trigger is hanging. I could see this action causing a deadlock if the trigger is executed in another transaction, but my understanding is that the trigger will be in the same transaction as the original query.

I tried reproducing this manually on my own, but I can only get it to reproduce in one deployment environment

Comment: That can never block. Your code must do something different.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am pretty sure after doing more debugging that the blocking PID is that of the original transaction. I am at a loss but it keeps coming back to seem that I am blocking myself. I don't fully understand how triggers run when initiated from within a transaction already

Comment: They run in the same transaction. Log transactions and statements in the database to see what happens.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ok, thank you. There may be some logic I am missing, but moving the insert (and trigger fired by it, implicitly) outside of the transaction removed the deadlock. I'm curious if this has something to do with JDBI, but I'm still at a loss. At least I have a fix for now

Comment: The deadlock must be with a different transaction, perhaps involving tables with a foreign key relationship.